# Error in deploying a rails app to heroku, bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

Upon running the command `git push heroku master` I got the error:

```
remote:        Downloading nokogiri-1.8.2 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile
remote:        (mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)).
remote:        Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update nokogiri` should
remote:        fix the problem.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fathomless-journey-80413.
remote:
```

I stumbled upon this page (https://forum.theodinproject.com/t/heroku-installfest/28/2)  which
suggested the steps below:

- In your Gemfile, change:

  > gem 'pg'

  to

  > gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
- Delete the file called Gemfile.lock
- Run bundle install --without production
- Run git commit -am "add version to pg"
- Run git push Heroku master

Above steps solved my problem but now I'm getting a similar error again

```
remote:        Downloading actionpack-4.2.10 revealed dependencies not in the API or the
remote:        lockfile (rack-test (~> 0.6.2)).
remote:        Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update actionpack`
remote:        should fix the problem.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fathomless-journey-80413.
remote:
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'




# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.10'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'pg'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '>= 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

This is my gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activejob (= 4.2.10)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.10)
      activemodel (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.10)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.4)
    binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
    crass (1.0.6)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.12.2)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    loofah (2.5.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.0)
    nokogiri (1.10.9)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (0.20.0)
    rack (1.6.13)
    rack-test (0.7.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (4.2.10)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activejob (= 4.2.10)
      activemodel (= 4.2.10)
      activerecord (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.10)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rdoc (6.2.1)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (1.1.0)
      rdoc (>= 5.0)
    spring (2.1.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.7)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  pg (~> 0.20.0)
  rails (= 4.2.10)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (>= 0.4.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

Any help would be appreciated...
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Output for `bundle update actionpack` gives me:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.6
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using minitest 5.14.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.7
Using activesupport 4.2.10
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.9
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.5.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 4.2.10
Using rack 1.6.13
Using rack-test 0.7.0
Using actionpack 4.2.10
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 4.2.10
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.10
Using activemodel 4.2.10
Using arel 6.0.4
Using activerecord 4.2.10
Using debug_inspector 0.0.3
Using binding_of_caller 0.8.0
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using byebug 11.1.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 1.0.1
Using railties 4.2.10
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using ffi 1.12.2
Using jbuilder 2.9.1
Using jquery-rails 4.3.5
Using pg 0.20.0
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 4.2.10
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using rdoc 6.2.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.7.4
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using sdoc 1.1.0
Using spring 2.1.0
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using uglifier 4.2.0
Using web-console 2.3.0
Bundler attempted to update actionpack but its version stayed the same
Bundle updated!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
```

EDIT: I think that somehow the fault was due to installing ruby via `apt-get` so I removed it and installed ruby all over again using rvm and it worked out!!!!!
Thanks for your suggestions..

Comment: Did you follow the error message to run `bundle update actionpack`?

Comment: yes I did but it says 'Bundler attempted to update actionpack but its version stayed the same'

Comment: I see `bundle update nokogiri` in the original error posted? Have you run that command locally? What happens?

Comment: 'bundle update nokogiri' just tried to update the gem. Since it was already updated i got the 'Bundler attempted to update nokogiri but its version stayed the same' message

Comment: I tried a lot of commands `bundle install` , `bundle update` , installed mini_portile2-2.3.0, 
uninstalled then reinstall bundler, reinstall nokogiri . In the end the solution listed above worked for me but now I'm stuck with actionpack

Comment: Did you commit `Gemfile.lock`?